# Please reopen 'How far in advance should you book a flight from Hong Kong to Canada?'?

Tags: discussion

I have tried to narrow [my question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/67149/13759) by focusing on Hong Kong instead of Asia. Is this specific enough now?

Answer (score 1):

As of the moment, the question is still not suitable for this site.
"Should" is clearly a value-based judgement, something that depends on the opinion and point of view of the individual involved. Especially as it's not clear what it is you want to acheive. Some would say you "should" bookas soon as possible, to guarantee a seat early. Some will say that you "should" leave it until the last minute, in case your plans change.

Comment: The article they linked to makes it very obvious that it's about price. If you think that needs to be explicit in the question itself to avoid link rot etc, that's fine, but it'd take seconds to edit it in and tell the asker what you've done so they know for next time.